# CasperJS: exit not working

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Trying to open random pages through casperJS start method but some pages are loading properly and some of them are not, so in this scenario it is not exiting from casperjs.
It is getting stuck in console then need to manually exit from console using CTR+C.

```
casper.start("some url", function() {

    if(this.status().currentHTTPStatus == 200) {
        casper.echo("page is loading");
    } else {
        casper.echo("page is in error ");
        this.exit();
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you call `casper.run()` in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using this.exit as below. casper.run(function() { this.exit(); }); in case some page is not responding or taking longer time to load then it is getting stuck, i want this to be exit forcefully.

Comment: Is there a way to set timeout if page is not loaded in the given timeframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it by a then step with a global [stepTimeout](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#steptimeout) option.

Sample code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  stepTimeout: 10000 //10s 
})

casper.start()

casper.then(funtion(){
  casper.open(url)
})

casper.run()
```

Comment: @DJJ Welcome. If there is no further question, you may set my answer as accepted...

Answer (score 0):

Try `bypass()` to ignore the next *then*s.

```
casper.start("some url", function() {
    if(this.status().currentHTTPStatus == 200) {
        casper.echo("page is loading");
    } else {
        casper.echo("page is in error ");
        this.bypass(2); // Will not execute the then functions.
    }
}).then(function() {
    // The 1st then function.
}).then(function() {
    // The 2nd then function.
})

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo('Something');
    this.exit(); // <--- Here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i am using this.exit as below.   casper.run(function() {
     this.exit();   
});                                                                                                                          if some page is not responded then it is not forcefully exiting.

Comment: I've edited the answer and let me know if you still need another solution.

Comment: Is there a way to set timeout if page is not loaded in the given timeframe?

Comment: In my case control is not moving to if else part